# Sending a message without Flushing in Serilog

Tags: c#, serilog

Usually, in order to be sure all events are sent to Serilog, one has to call `CloseAndFlush` method. Is it possible to configure Serilog so that certain events (e.g. Fatals) are sent immediately?

Comment: Which sink are you using?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt

I'm working with App Insights sink. If I get an error, I wouldn't like to wait until App Insights sends it and would like to send it right away. I think it can be done by manipulating the Telemetry Client but I was curious if Serilog has something. Perhaps I can manually tell Serilog to flush but not dispose the logger since I still need it?

Comment: No, not at present - if it can be done via the `TelemetryClient` that would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if it's possible, though I'm not sure it will work out. In the worst case scenario we'll introduce direct AI + file logging in extremely crucial places and leave Serilog do its job in other 99% of the system.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using Serilog's [audit logging functionality](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/820). More generally, whether or not log events are buffered is an implementation detail of the sink, not Serilog itself. For example, the default File sink flushes every event by default.

Comment: Yeah, I've expected it would be Sink's concern rather that logger's. Thanks for the audit link. It doesn't solve my issue directly, but it's still useful to keep it in mind.